# Access parquet files in Azure DataBricks by R via RODBC

Tags: r, azure, apache-spark, databricks, rodbc

I successfully configured connection to Azure DataBricks cluster and can query tables with

```r
conn <- odbcConnect("AzureDatabricks")
sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM my_table")
```

but I need to access parquet files.
In Databricks I can do it with this code:

```
%sql

Select * FROM parquet.`/path/to/folder`
```

If I try this by R as

```r
sqlQuery(conn, "Select * FROM parquet.`/path/to/folder`")
```

I receive error:

```r
[Simba][SQLEngine] Table or view not found: SPARK.parquet./path/to/folder"
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'Select * FROM parquet.`/path/to/folder`
```

Is there way to access parquet files via RODBC?

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing this issue due to an error in your sql query itself. When you run `Select * FROM parquet./path/to/folder`,  command you will not see table or view not found due to syntax error.

**Example:** Sample example for understanding the issue (when you run SELECT * FROM parquer.'somepath'), you will see the syntax error.

[image]

**Note:** After creating a Dataframe from parquet file, you have to register it as a temp table to run **sql queries** on it.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("src/main/resources/peopleTwo.parquet")

df.printSchema

// after registering as a table you will be able to run sql queries
df.registerTempTable("people")

sqlContext.sql("select * from people").collect.foreach(println)
```

**Reference:** [Spark SQL guide - Parquet files](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `UseNativeQuery=1;` parameter to the odbc connection string.

Examlpe: `Driver={Simba Spark ODBC Driver};Host=[serverHost];Port=443;HTTPPath=[httpPath];ThriftTransport=2;SSL=1;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=[pwd];UseNativeQuery=1;`

https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#ansi-sql-92-query-support-in-odbc